# ||= operator not behave correctly by using require in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby, sorry for this Noobie Question

```
#file1.rb

a = 1



#file2.rb

require './file1'

a ||= 2

puts a # show 2, not 1 as expected
```

I can't figure out why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` in file1 is local to file1. It will not be visible in file2. The behaviour is correct.

You can use instance variable to make variables visible in other files.

```
#file1.rb

@a = 1


#file2.rb

require './file1'

@a ||= 2

puts @a # >> 1
```

Comment: `puts a` needs to be `puts @a`.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that one :)

Comment: So it's not simply append file1 before file2. Could you explain more about why the local variable is not exist in the file2?

Comment: Because it's a local variable. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in. That's why they are called local variables, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@a` (an instance variable) instead. `a` as you have it is a local variable and cannot be accessed in that way.